# Allow label overflow or increase allowed width of my BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter

One of my 4 BottomNavigationBarItems in the BottomNavigationBar has more than 9 characters in the label, which means the overflow (triple dots) occurs.

Is there a way to prevent this? To change the maximum allowed characters in a BottomNavigationBarItem, or to allow text overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Below code will allow the overflow text to show in the next lines(properties of BottomnavigationBar)

```
selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible,),
unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible,),
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise overflow was an option from the TextStyle widget, so this is an option. But ideally I just want it to utilise the rest of the space on one line (as it has space but seems to be limited). I haven't found any other solution and the google docs suggest using much shorter words so it might be a forced rule.

Comment: Yeah, you're right we can't use that space. But there is an alternative that you can show only the selected label in the space like using the type as type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting . Other than that if you want to show all the labels and make use of the space too then TabBar is the option you can use property isScrollable.

Answer (score -1):

there is a lot of ways to do that :

1 - you can set the type to fixed :

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed

)
```

2 - you can minimize the size of your text

3 - you can warp it with `Wrap` widget

also some code in your question will be usefull

Comment: thanks but BottomNavigationBarType.fixed doesn't change the amount of text a label can have in BottomNavigationBar, and I can't change the text (it's simply the text that the client wants to use). I'll look in to using the Wrap widget but from memory this won't work on BottomNavigationBar

Comment: Just checked. Spacing isn't a problem, so Wrap widget won't help. The problem is the max characters allowed in a BottomNavigationBarItem is 9 by default. I'm asking if there is a way to change that.